# How to avoid same Notification creates at many times in android status bar?

Tags: android

I am developing event reminder application in android.In my application user can set event time and i am generating status bar notification at the specified time.But in my application it generates the same notification(notification ID)at many times in status bar.Please help me how to avoid that?

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
notification = new Notification(R.drawable.logo, "Notification",System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context,strText, "@"+strDate+ strCorrectTime,contentIntent);
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
mNotificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(intent.getExtras().get("NotifyCount").toString()), notification);
```

[image]this is coding..[image]

Comment: this is not the answer but just a suggestion, the method notification.setLatestEventInfo is now deprecated i guess your app wont work for newer android versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use `System.currentTimeMillis()` as a notification id.
instead define a constant:

```
public static final long TRAY_ID = 237864827364; // let your IDE generate it
```

and use this before each `mNotificationManager.notify(..)`:

```
( (NotificationManager)getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE ) ).cancel( TRAY_ID );
```

Answer (score 0):

The System time should work fine.Plese check your BroadcastReceiver how many time called.
It may be called two times.
And use the for unique id for notification.

```
int notitime=new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt();

mNotificationManager.notify(notitime, notification);
```

notitime is the unique id for the notification.